# how can i get gmail tasks on android

Tags: android

how can i get gmail tasks on android?

i really need gmail tasks

please help me

Comment: This does not seem like a programming question. Is it?

Comment: I think it's called Google Tasks, not GMail tasks. You can find a description the API here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/ . If you are looking for an app, search the Android market for 'gtasks'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the browser, go to http://gmail.com/tasks.
2. Press < Menu > and select Bookmarks. Go ahead and add the bookmark to the Tasks site.
3. Press < Home > to return to your home screen.
4. Press < Menu > and select Add.
5. Select Shortcut > Bookmark.
6. Choose the bookmark to the Tasks site. A new icon instantly appears on your home screen, offering you quick access to Tasks.

Courtesy of http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=5c70246ca3884f20&hl=en